# Проверить наличие определенной строчки в Spinner

Tags: java, android

Имеется у меня такой кусок кода :

```
if (Objects.equals(prefs.getString(SPINNER_2, spin_state_2), getResources().getString(R.string.state_1)))
    {
        int pos = adapter_2.getPosition(getResources().getString(R.string.state_1));
        spinner_2.setSelection(pos);
    }
```

т.е. берем сохраненное в настройках значение, ищем какая позиция адаптера ему соответствует и, в зависимости от этого значения, выставляем для `spinner_2` нужное значение из имеющихся. Но, может возникнуть ситуация, когда в настройках сохранено значение `state_1`, а в адаптере спиннера такое значение отсутствует.

Как поставить условие проверки наподобие такого?

```
if (Objects.equals(prefs.getString(SPINNER_2, spin_state_2), getResources().getString(R.string.state_1)))
    {
        if (в адаптере есть пункт со значением `state_1`)
        {
            int pos = adapter_2.getPosition(getResources().getString(R.string.state_1));
            spinner_2.setSelection(pos);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напишите в адаптере функцию, которая будет возвращать все его item, например:

```
ArrayList<String> getItems(){
    return adapterList;
}
```

Тогда условие будет выглядеть так:

```
if (adapter_1.getItems().contains("your_text"){
    ...
}
```

Как вариант, сразу проверяйте в адаптере:

```
boolean isContains(String text){
    return adapterList.contains(text);
}
```

и `if (adapter_1.isContains("your_text")){}`